# Koszul duality between Weyl and Clifford algebras?

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, koszul-duality, koszul-algebras, clifford-algebras, weyl-algebra

### Koszul duality

Given a finite-dimensional $k$-vector space $V$ (I am happy taking $k = \mathbb{C}$ anywhere in the following if it makes a difference) and a subspace $R \subseteq V \otimes V$, we can form the *quadratic algebra*
$$A = A(V,R) = T(V)/ \langle R \rangle,$$
where $\langle R \rangle$ is the 2-sided ideal in the tensor algebra generated by $R$.

We can then form the quadratic algebra $A^! = A(V^*, R^\perp)$, where
$$  R^\perp = \{ \phi \in V^* \otimes V^* \mid \phi(R) = 0 \},  $$
and we have identified $V^* \otimes V^*$ with $(V \otimes V)^*$.  This algebra $A^!$ is also quadratic by construction, and is known as the *Koszul dual* of $A$.  It's pretty clear that $(A^!)^! \simeq A$.

One example of this is given by the symmetric and exterior algebras of a vector space and its dual, i.e. for a finite-dimensional vector space $V$, we have
$$  S(V)^! \simeq \Lambda(V^*), \quad \Lambda(V)^! \simeq S(V^*).  $$

### Clifford and Weyl algebras

Now suppose that $V$ is even-dimensional, say $\mathrm{dim}_\mathbb{C}(V) = 2n$, and let $h: V \otimes V \to k$ be a nondegenerate symmetric bilinear form on $V$.  The *Clifford algebra* is the algebra
$$ \mathrm{Cl}(V,h)  = T(V)/\langle x - h (x) \mid x \in S^2(V) \rangle,  $$
and this can be viewed as a deformation of the exterior algebra in the sense that the Clifford algebra is naturally filtered and the associated graded is $\Lambda(V)$.  If $h$ is nondegenerate, then (over $\mathbb{C}$, at least) we can show that $\mathrm{Cl}(V,h) \simeq M_{2^n}(\mathbb{C})$.

If we take instead a nondegenerate alternating (i.e. symplectic) form $g:V \otimes V \to k$, then we can form the *Weyl algebra*
$$  A_n = A_n(V,g) = T(V)/\langle x - g(x) \mid x \in \Lambda^2(V) \rangle. $$
This too has a natural filtration from the tensor algebra, and the associated graded is $S(V)$.

These two deformations share some features in common.  For instance, the Weyl algebra is isomorphic to the algebra of polynomial differential operators on $\mathbb{C}[x_1, \dots, x_n]$, and one can think of the Clifford algebra as being a $\mathbb{Z}/2$-graded analogue of that via creation and annihilation operators on $\Lambda(V)$.  Both algebras are simple.

### Main question

Is there any sort of non-quadratic Koszul duality that relates the Clifford and Weyl algebras?

Comment: One can make both algebras quadratic. Add element "z^2" which is central and modify the relations like changing 1-> z^2 i.e. [x,d]=z^2 in Weyl case and xd+dx = z^2 in Clifford case. And may ask whether the two modified algebras Koszul dual in the standard sense. I am not sure this is something good trick, just a comment...

Comment: I begin to remember that such trick is used somewhere in Feigin Tsygan works. They convert universal enveloping algebra into quadratic algebra - like this:  adding central variable t, and modifying relations to [xi, xj] = c_ij^k xk*t - so algebra becomes quadratic...

Comment: Surely, you can homogenize nonhomogeneous quadratic relations, but the homogenizations of the Clifford and Weyl algebras wouldn't be quadratic dual to each other.   Generally, I don't think there can be a positive answer to the original question, if only because there is no natural correspondence between symmetric and skew-symmetric forms $g$ and $h$ on a given vector space, or indeed, on any two different vector spaces.  A theory of nonhomogeneous quadratic duality exists, but it does not relate these two algebras to each other.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Non-homogeneous Koszul duality is now well-understood. Here are a few references:

- I guess the original reference is

> L. E. Positsel′ski˘ı. Nonhomogeneous
>   quadratic duality and curvature.
>   Funktsional. Anal. i Prilozhen.,
>   27:57–66, 96, 1993.

- for a more systematic study you can have alook at

> A. Polishchuk and L. Positselski.
>   Quadratic algebras, volume 37 of
>   University Lecture Series. American
>   Mathematical Society, Providence, RI,
>   2005.

- As far as I remember the [new book of Loday and Vallette](http://math.unice.fr/~brunov/Operads.pdf) discusses this too (see $\S 3.6$).
- You can find the statement that Weyl and Clifford algebras are Koszul in the inhomogenous sens in [this paper of Braverman-Gaistgory](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9411113) ($\S 5.3$).

Nevertheless, as it is said in Leonid Positselski's comment, Weyl and Clifford algebras are not Koszul dual to each other. The reason is that inhomogeneous Koszul duality is inhomogeneous!

- quadratic-linear algebras are dual to DG quadratic algebras (e.g. the universal envelopping algebra of a Lie algebra is Koszul dual its Chevalley-Eilenberg algebra).
- quadratic--linear-constant algebra (e.g. Weyl or Clifford, for which there is even no linear part) are dual to curved quadratic DG algebras. E.g. for the Weyl algebra $\mathcal W_{(V,\omega)}$, its Kozsul dual is the pair $(\wedge(V^*),\omega)$ where the symplectic form $\omega$ is viewed as a curvature (a degree 2 element) in the exterior algebra.

Answer (score 1):

If Koszul dual is used for computing resolutions (for $k$ as $A$-module or for $A$ as $A$-bimodule), you can use this idea to find a small resolution for the Weyl algebra. In this way we computed Hochschild (co)homology of the Weyl algebra (and variations).

"Usually", if the associated graded of something has a small resolution (e.g. because it is Koszul), the original one has a big chance to share this property.